# How to unfold a list into list of lists with yield?

Tags: f#

Another impractical exercise... I have a function that unfolds a list into a sequence of lists starting with each list element:

```
[ 1; 2; 3 ] |> Seq.unfold (fun lst -> 
  match lst with
  | x::xs -> Some(lst, xs)
  | [] -> None
  )
```

which yields

```
  seq [[1; 2; 3]; [2; 3]; [3]]
```

I tried to write the same with seq/yield, but failed... Is this possible? Any other nice ways to write this function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let rec seqOfLists lst =
    seq {
        match lst with
        | _::xs -> 
            yield lst
            yield! seqOfLists xs
        | [] -> ()
    }
```